# Blank Regular Expression

Tags: regex, wordpress, validation

Using `Cforms` and adding some validation in, thought i'd throw in the Honeypot method as well. With `cforms` it allows you to add a `Regex` into a field, but I have been trying to figure out how to create a "blank" regex.

the best I have so far is to put a space into the field then use this regex: `^\s`
This works perfectly well, but just out of pure interest, is there a pure blank version, so that if ANY character is typed in then it won't validate.

Thanks

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063977/regex-empty-string-or-email/5063991#5063991) may help

Comment: Same method as posted below, but for some reason it won't validate if left blank! Looks like I will just stick to the space method :)

Answer (score 3):

Like this? `^$` (start+end with nothing in between).

Comment: Tried this method, but even if left blank it doesn't validate

Comment: @DamianSmith I don't know what "Cforms" is, maybe the validation logic works different than expected.

Comment: This should work in cforms - try using something like:

Phone||^$|err:Please leave this field blank|html5:0¤0¤¤¤¤¤

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another way of doing the same thing: `.{0}`