# How to write a regex either mathes to empty character set or contains a specific sequence

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex for a text-box field validation on the JSF page. I need this field to be an empty, or contains a sequence of `[a-z]1[a-z]54`. How can I do that?

Comment: what's stopping you?

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't how to write a condition in regex

Comment: time to learn perhaps?

Comment: You don't need to do a regex conditional. Just disjunct the entire regex match with `string.length == 0`

Comment: @MitchWheat I mean, if the string doesn't match [a-z]1[a-z]54 then it shall match an empty string.

Comment: @quantumtremor I know, but unfortunately I need to do it via regex. Is it possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex empty string or email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063977/regex-empty-string-or-email)

Comment: why the vote to close? it's not asking for an off-site resource, there are 3 answers here all basically equivalent

Answer (score 4):

You could try this also,

```
^([a-z]1[a-z]54)?$
```

`?` after the capturing group would make the whole capturing group as an optional one.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/2)

Answer (score 3):

try this one:  `^([a-z]1[a-z]54|)$`

Answer (score 2):

This regex may help you `^[a-z]{1,54}$|^$`