# Validation for EmailAdress gets triggered for optional field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I have this email validation attribute

```
[EmailAddress]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Email is too long!")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

And it works fine, but the problem is when I type the email, and then erase it, the form still asks me to insert correct email even though the field is not required.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will accept empty string or exact an email id

```
"^$|^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"
```

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37791350/4264614)

Comment: Im sorry what do I do exacly with this string?

Comment: I was not the one who marked it.
I just gave you up arrow if that soothes your soul.
I will read more into regex, thanks!

Comment: @ŠarūnasKaulakis My apologies. please see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you kind Sir, you made it work and my headache is relieved.
Have a great day.

Comment: Although it solved your problem, it should be another solution without using regex..

Comment: @ŠarūnasKaulakis you are welcome and hope you learn something which is very much required with different kinds of string validation.

Comment: @SelimYıldız what is another solution you suggesting ?